# How do I display the highest average of checkbox when multiple checkboxes checked in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am trying to make a program that has 6 checkboxes and when one is checked a label displays the actors take in average, but if more than one is checked the label will only show the highest average of the checked boxes.

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    SC = ((Val(425488741) + Val(555909803) + Val(868659354) + Val(966435555) + Val(720388023) + Val(617520987)) / 6)

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "Sean Connery $" & SC

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

    GL = 513445231

    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "George Lazenby $" & GL

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged

    RM = ((Val(785677477) + (426826774) + (666367656)  + (624527272) + (481005579) + (405873493) + (316186616)) / 7)

    If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "Roger Moore $" & RM

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged

    TD = ((Val(362876056) + (271586451)) / 2)

    If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "Timothy Dalton $" & TD

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub CheckBox5_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox5.CheckedChanged

    PB = ((Val(499954330) + (465588535) + (504705882)  + (546490272)) / 4)

    If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "Pierce Brosnan $" & PB

        Exit Sub

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub CheckBox6_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox6.CheckedChanged

    DC = ((Val(640803677) + (586090727)) / 2)

    If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then

        Label3.Text = "Daniel Craig $" & DC

        Exit Sub

    End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, when asking a question, please do not include all the unnecessary details. If understand your problem correctly, this is one possible simple solution:

```
Dim incomes = New Integer() {100, 2000, 500}
Dim names = New String() {"John", "Tim", "Allan"}

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim maxIncome As Integer = 0
    Dim name As String = ""

    For i = 0 To incomes.Length - 1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) And incomes(i) > maxIncome Then
            maxIncome = incomes(i)
            name = names(i)
        End If
    Next

    Label1.Text = name & " $" & maxIncome
End Sub
```

For this code to work you need to create a CheckedListBox with 3 items in it's collection. However, this approach might lead to a very bad code once there are many values. In that case you should use a database or at least a structure like:

```
Structure People
    Dim name As String
    Dim income As Integer
    Dim checkBox As CheckBox
End Structure
```

Also the is no need to write `Exit Sub` anywhere in your code, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** Saulius is correct in that you should use a database and that you should use a checkedlistbox instead to make it much easier. However, I will just assume you want to use separate checkboxes for whatever reason.

**Solution:**

Create an Actor Class

```
Public Class Actor
   Property Name As String
   Property TotalValue As Double
End Class
```

In your main form

```
Public Sub DisplayHighestPaidActor(ByVal actorName As String, ByVal isChecked As Boolean)

    If isChecked Then
        'Add the Actor
        selectedActors.Add((From actor In allActors
                            Where actor.Name = actorName).FirstOrDefault())

        'Order the Actors
        selectedActors = (From actor In selectedActors
                          Order By actor.TotalValue Descending).ToList()
    Else
        'Remove the Actor
        selectedActors.Remove((From actor In allActors
                               Where actor.Name = actorName).FirstOrDefault())

        'Order the Actors
        selectedActors = (From actor In selectedActors
                          Order By actor.TotalValue Descending).ToList()

    End If

    If (selectedActors.Count > 0) Then

        'Display the highest value
        lblHighestPaidActor.Text = selectedActors.Item(0).Name.ToString() _
                          + " $" + selectedActors.Item(0).TotalValue.ToString()
    Else
        lblHighestPaidActor.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    DisplayHighestPaidActor("Sean Connery", CheckBox1.Checked)

End Sub


Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged

    DisplayHighestPaidActor("George Lazenby", CheckBox2.Checked)

End Sub


Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged

    DisplayHighestPaidActor("Roger Moore", CheckBox3.Checked)

End Sub
```